# Search for a track of a specific user

Tags: search, soundcloud

I would like to search a track among my own soundcloud tracks using the search api.

Following the [documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks), I should be able to do so by hitting such URL: https://api.soundcloud.com/users/[user_id]/tracks?client_id=[client_id]&q=[query_words], but the results I get are all my tracks and not only the ones matching my query.

Is this the normal behavior or is there another way to filter a user's tracks ?

Comment: I just tested the /users endpoint and I'm seeing the same results. The 'q' parameter seems to be ignored.

Comment: The `q` parameter only works on the `/tracks` endpoint, and not `/users/:id/tracks`.